# for loop best practice

Tags: php

As far as I know second and third expressions are executed every time in a for loop.

I always took for granted performance wise second option is recommended, can anyone confirm this?

1) `for($i=0;$i<=dosomething();$i++) [...]`

2)

```
 $max = dosomething();
 for($i=0;$i<=$max;$i++) [...]
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't call a function inside of a loop definition because that function will be executed every iteration. When you only have a small loop the effect is negligible, however if you have a loop of hundreds or thousands of iterations you'll definitely notice.

But even if you only have a small loop, it's just bad practice. So in a word: don't.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your dosomething() function returns different values and it can be done in a single shot, it's better to use the second method.

$options = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$element_count = count($options);

Functions like count() that returns same value in multiple calls can be saved in a one variable and use it in your for loop.

If you are very strict for performance, use ++$i instead of $i++

Answer (score 3):

The second method is always going to preform better, especially if there is substantial work to be done in doSomething(). If you are only doing tens of loops, and doSomething() is just returning a local variable, then it won't make a noticeable difference.

Answer (score -2):

Yes I confirm you can search benchmarks if you want.

Though I don't know if it's true if it's only a getter to an object